# Member for 5 days, and fanatic-badge?

Tags: bug, new-users, users, user-interface

The fanatic-badge is described as follows:

```
Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days
```

This means (if I don't understand it wrong), that you have to be a member for at least 100 days, and visit stackoverflow daily.

However, I came across user with this badge who is, according to its user-site, a `member for 5 days`.

The user also has more than 4000 reputation, although it should't be possible for him to exceed 1500 due to the daily maximum.

I doubt there is a bug in stackexchange, so what does `member for` actually stand for, if it's not the time since when the user registered?

Comment: I'm guessing this would have to be from an account merge.

Comment: Merged accounts are awarded badges from the account merged in.